# shell script if condition not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have written a script to run some linux commands and capture the exceptions in an if clause and output the results.  Basically each of the variables in the below excerpt of the code represent the command execution status and i want to exit the script successfully if all commands are executed succesfully. Otherwise i want to exit with one. While testing the script i had intentionally made on command fail and the output of one variable for example X8 is 1. In this scenario the below is not working as expected. It's showing me the success message instead of script failed message. Not sure why

```
if [ $X1 != 0 ] &&  [ $X2 != 0 ] &&  [ $X3 != 0 ] && [ $X4 != 0 ] && [ $X5 != 0 ] && [ $X6 != 0 ] && [ $X7 != 0 ] && [ $X8 != 0 ];
then echo "script failed"; exit 1;     
else echo "success"; fi;
```

Comment: You should use `-ne` for integer tests I think. Chaining with `&&` requires *all* variables to be non-zero to get failure; don't you want `||` here?

Comment: You might consider (assume bash/ksh/zsh): `if ((x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8 > 0))`

Comment: Or, keep one variable that accumulates the exit status of your commands: `((status += $?))`. Or, use `set -e` which will abort your script as soon as a command exits with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script, add this:

```
trap 'echo "Error $? at $LINENO; aborting." 1>&2; exit $?' ERR
```

Then, anytime anything throws an uncaught error, the script will bail with the above message and exit with the exit code of the error.  You can change `$?` to `1` if you really want to use an exit code of 1 for any error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `[` which is short hand for `test`. From `man test`:

> ```
>   STRING1 != STRING2
>          the strings are not equal
> ```

You're using wrong tool for the job. What you need is

> ```
>  INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>          INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
> ```

Second, you have multiple conditions to test here. Instead of using one lengthy if statement , try to sum the output of each variable, as glenn suggested in comments, and test that. Alternatively, evaluate the output of each command right after it exist. There's no point in running others, if you're going to quit because that command's output anyway.

Here's a looping approach:

```
for i in $X1 $X2 $X3 ; 
do 
    [ $i -ne 0 ] && { echo "something failed"; exit 1; }
done
echo "Everything OK"
```

The trick here is that you're doing same test for each and every one of the variables, and if that test fails, the script will never get to the "Everything OK" part